# why does $2\sin2\theta-\cos2\theta=\sqrt5\sin(2\theta-\phi)(\phi=\arctan(1/2))$?

Tags: trigonometry

why does $2\sin2\theta-\cos2\theta=\sqrt5\sin(2\theta-\phi)(\phi=\arctan(1/2))$?

I was thinking if the equation is related to the double angle formula but didn't work

Comment: Expand the rhs with the addition formula

Answer (score 1):

Using the "sine of sum" you can rewrite the right hand side as

$$\sin(2\theta - \phi) = \sin(2\theta)\cos(\phi) - \cos(2\theta)\sin(\phi)$$

Now remember also that

$$\sin(\arctan(x)) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

$$\cos(\arctan(x)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

Now since here  $x = \phi = \arctan(1/2)$ we have that

$$\sin(\phi) = \sin(\arctan(1/2)) = \dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{5}$$

$$\cos(\phi) = \cos(\arctan(1/2)) = \dfrac{2\sqrt{5}}{5}$$

Then I believe you can proceed.